# How do I get the links to the internal distribution builds with expo/expo-github-action?

Tags: android, ios, expo, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I am building internal distribution builds for a React Native Expo app via GitHub actions and EAS Build. The workflow is triggered on push using `expo/expo-github-action@v7`. Once the build is finished, the action logs 2 URLs (and 2 QR codes) where the `.apk` and `.ipa` can be downloaded:

[image: screenshot of log file]

I want to get those links programmatically so I can use them in the next step to notify my Slack channel, for example.

I've looked in the documentation, but it's very generic. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have a look at the Action's documentation: https://github.com/expo/expo-github-action/tree/main/preview#available-outputs They have an example with Slack notifications as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this the "hard way" because `expo-github-action` does not have any outputs.

First, I needed to get the build output as JSON. I did so with the `--json` switch:

```
eas build --profile preview --platform all --non-interactive --json
```

Second, I stored the result in a variable like so:

```
build_json=$(eas build --profile preview --platform all --non-interactive --json)
```

Next, I parsed the JSON and extracted the links out of it:

```
android_link=$(echo $build_json | jq -r '.[] | select(.platform=="ANDROID") | .artifacts.applicationArchiveUrl')
ios_link=$(echo $build_json | jq -r '.[] | select(.platform=="IOS") | .artifacts.applicationArchiveUrl')
```

Finally, I've assigned the variables to outputs:

```
EOF=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 status=none | base64)
echo "build_json<<$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "$build_json" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "android_link=$android_link" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "ios_link=$ios_link" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Note that the system that GitHub Actions uses to create outputs is brittle and does not work well with apices or newlines, so in the case of `build_json`, the only safe alternative is to use a random separator instead of the `<name>=<variable>` syntax.

I could then use the outputs with `steps.<step id>.outputs.android_link`, etc.

The overall solution looks like this:

```
build_json=$(eas build --profile preview --platform all --non-interactive --json)
android_link=$(echo $build_json | jq -r '.[] | select(.platform=="ANDROID") | .artifacts.applicationArchiveUrl')
ios_link=$(echo $build_json | jq -r '.[] | select(.platform=="IOS") | .artifacts.applicationArchiveUrl')
EOF=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 status=none | base64)
echo "build_json<<$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "$build_json" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "android_link=$android_link" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "ios_link=$ios_link" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Hopefully it will help the next person save day of investigation or so!